# When you have to use previous or older kernel due to compatibility or dependencies, how long is it safe to use them?

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, security

I'm sure a bunch of people are having this issue now.
I upgraded Fedora kernel with a magic button in "Software" app and Virtual Box vboxdrv isn't available yet for 5.8 . (Before this last kernel udgrade, previously been loaded with modprobe vboxdrv but vboxdrv is missing from the /usr/src/kernels/5.8.4-200.fc32.x86_64 dir.

Virtual Box is very important and since I only know how to deal with it's errors by running modprobe or reinstalling, I am faced with booting into the 5.7 kernel.

But this goes against my limited idea of security. Is it safe to boot into old kernels for a while to do your Vbox work or... is it safe to use it for longer?
I understand kernels do an awful lot and bring a lot of new features when they are upgraded and are not necessarily going to "damage the security of your system", but I do wonder how correct or wrong I am about that.

Comment: Don't use vbox, use virt-manager!

Comment: @IporSircer OK I guess it might be time to follow that advice!

Comment: There is possbily no actual answer to this but I really still wonder if there are guidelines to follow when being in such a situation.